# Logback - Multiple syslog appenders

Tags: logback

I'm logging to syslog with a syslog appender as shown below:

```
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <syslogHost>localhost</syslogHost>
        <facility>LOCAL6</facility>
        <suffixPattern>app: %logger{20} %msg</suffixPattern>
    </appender>
```

But I've got a new requirement where I want to send some logs to the "LOCAL5" facility instead of LOCAL6. I've read the logback configuration documentation http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html but I'm still not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two syslog appenders one for LOCAL6 and other for LOCAL5

```
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <syslogHost>localhost</syslogHost>
        <facility>LOCAL6</facility>
        <suffixPattern>app: %logger{20} %msg</suffixPattern>
    </appender>


<appender name="SYSLOG1" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <syslogHost>localhost</syslogHost>
        <facility>LOCAL5</facility>
        <suffixPattern>app: %logger{20} %msg</suffixPattern>
    </appender>
```

Advantage is that you a customize the logs( some logs) using filters, pattern, logger names etc. And SyslogAppender extends UnsyncronizedAppender.

Reason being you cannot use single appender is that method `facilityStringToint(String facilityStr)` in class `SyslogAppender.java` accepts String which then compares which standard facility using equals. 
Example

```
     if ("KERN".equalsIgnoreCase(facilityStr)) {
          return SyslogConstants.LOG_KERN;
     }
```